# Sending JSON messages to WCF service when DataContracts have inheritance hierarchy

Tags: wcf, json

I have a wcf web service which is configured for JSON. But my data contracts have inheritance chain. I have a datacontract called **RequestMessage** and two other datacontracts like **Derived1** and **Derived2** which are derived from RequestMessage. My service contract has a service operation which is like this **BaseResponse GetResult(BaseRequest request)**. I am decorating the servie contract with KnownTypes. This works fine when used with basicHttpBinding(any SOAP based binding). Will this also works when JSON message is passed ?

Will the service able to identify the proper type of object when I send any of the Derived1 or Deerived2 JSON objects?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are obviously using polymorphic types. Microsoft's JSON, which is used for WCF, uses a non-standard extension where they add type information in a field called `__type`. If you add this field, it likely will work.

Details about what value you have to put at the `__type` key can be found on this [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412170.aspx) in the section "Advanced information".